# Javascript global (body) click event registration is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, dom-events

Android and Chrome events work fine, try the following options:

```
$window.onclick = function () {
   if ($scope.accountsMenuOpen) {
       $scope.accountsMenuOpen = false;
       $scope.$apply();
   }
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if ($scope.accountsMenuOpen) {
       $scope.accountsMenuOpen = false;
       $scope.$apply();
   }
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function () {
   if ($scope.accountsMenuOpen) {
       $scope.accountsMenuOpen = false;
       $scope.$apply();
   }
});
```

I double check and Javascript is enabled in Safari; also try with the following angularjs directive:

```
<body click-capture>
```

I just debug in Safari and click event is triggered in some elements (where elements are in a ng-controller context). I don't know why is not registered in all body elements.

Comment: If you're on a mobile touchscreen, you may need to listen for `touch` events instead of `click` events; although I would expect that to be fairly consistent accross browsers.

Comment: thanks for your comment ontouchstart will be ideal but it is not supported by safari https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp

Comment: Sounds like Safari is just gimped then. Search around to see what the typical fix is. There may be a polyfill available, or, Safari may refer to touch events as something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into touch events there is one available in safari, thanks [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) for the hint

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function () {   
  if ($scope.accountsMenuOpen) {
     $scope.accountsMenuOpen = false;
     $scope.$apply();
  }
});
```